# ROWNUM works in Oracle but fails with HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I have following query that work with oracle:

```
 SELECT * FROM Company WHERE Company.name LIKE ? AND ROWNUM <= 20;
```

For Test, I use HSQLDB this query fails and I have the follwing exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ROWNUM
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
```

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, rownum is something Oracle. To resolve it, don't rely on rownum but use another way to limit the resultset. I'm sure Spring-jdbc has logic for it.

Comment: Another good example why it's a bad idea to test on something that you don't use in production.

Comment: As already answered, you should turn on the ORA compatibility mode in HSQLDB and it will understand ROWNUM